# How do I resolve this error message to create an Enum: "Project 'MyFunProject' is not a J2SE 5.0 compliant project."

Tags: java, eclipse, enums

I am learning about using Enum in a project which will be used within a switch statement. I get this error message when I click >New>Enum from the project folder: "Project 'MyFunProject' is not a J2SE 5.0 compliant project."

My installed JREs (Preferences > Java > Installed JREs) includes JAVA SE 6 and JAVA SE 8, but only JAVA SE 8 is actually selected.  The error message seems to imply that I have some setting somewhere referencing Java SE 5, but I cannot find anything else to corroborate that theory.

Comment: Check "Preferences > Java > Compiler" and "Project Properties > Java Compiler"

Comment: I followed this link path and I found that my JDK compliance level was set to 1.4.  I reset it to 1.7 ( the highest available) and I am now able to create my Enum class ( I think it is a class, anyway).  Thank you!

Comment: @immibis I am not entirely sure how stackoverflow works, but if you leave an answer I can vote it up as the solution.  I am pretty sure the meat of the answer is in your comment.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can adjust your compiler compliance level in the Preferences window, under "Java > Compiler".

This can also be overridden on a per-project basis, in Project Properties, under "Java Compiler".

Make sure your compliance level is set to the JDK version you have (or the version you want to compile your code as).

**METHOD:**
Open the properties for the project, select the page "Java Compiler" and set the "Compiler Compliance level" to "1.5" or better.
[image]